# How could I assign key binding for `C-=`

Tags: key-bindings

In general I have key bindings as follows:

`(define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "C-h") 'isearch-del-char)`

Now I want to define a key binding for `C-=` (Control plus equal sign, which is next to Backspace on my keyboard); where it does not work.

Is it possible to do it?

Comment: Terminal emacs or GUI emacs? You may be able to do it in GUI emacs, but probably not in the terminal.

Comment: I meant terminal emacs, I am not good with gui @NickD

Comment: Say `C-h c C-=` in your emacs and see what it says: if it says `= runs the command self-insert-command` then it does not recognize `C-=` (note that you asked it about `C-=` and it answered about `=`). If it says `C-= is undefined` then you should be able to change it.

Comment: You are right, it returns as: `= runs the command self-insert-command`

Answer (score 1):

Without more context, the direct answer to "is it possible to generate a keybinding for `C-=`" is "Yes".

For example,

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "C-=") (lambda () (interactive) (message "Hello world!")))
```

There are many other ways.  For instance, my init contains the following [`use-package`](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package) definition:

```lisp
(use-package expand-region
  :ensure t
  :bind (("C-=" . er/expand-region)
         ("C-+" . er/contract-region)))
```

Both of these define global keybindings.

Key map specific bindings can be defined like you state in the question.  An example of this, again taken from my init, defines the `<insert>` key to insert an Org structure template only for buffers with Org mode enabled:

```lisp
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<insert>") 'org-insert-structure-template)
```

Comment: That is possible on GUI emacs and maybe terminal emacs for *some* terminals, but certainly not all of them (e.g. try it in gnome-terminal with  `emacs -nw`).